# Google Plus Share Image Selection

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

I've come into the recent trouble of a Google Pus share button pulling in an image that I can't find on my site. The page in question is http://www.iewc.com/products/wire-and-cable/aerospace-and-defense/coaxial-cable/m17111 . When trying to share via Google Plus, the share dialog pulls in an image that isn't specified in the markup for Google Plus, see here: [Incorrect image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWCaB.png) . But, if you click on the next or previous buttons on the image selector, the correct image is available. Is there a way to prevent the incorrect image from showing?

Comment: It looks like it should be working. You can test the metadata for you page with [this tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iewc.com%2Fproducts%2Fwire-and-cable%2Faerospace-and-defense%2Fcoaxial-cable%2Fm17111). I would recommend using a smaller square image instead of current one. That might be causing issues.

Comment: Although the tool Google provides show which one I'm trying to get to be the first image, it's still adding another image and I can't figure out where that image is coming from.

Comment: It's the [first image](http://www.iewc.com/img/layout/bodyTopRpt.png) in the HTML.